# return issues without pagination `glab issue list`

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I want to retrieve all issues from `myrepo` with the gitlab-cli.

The command `glab issue list -R myrepo -P 1000` returns a page containing with 100 issues, but I have 195 issues. Is this a limitation in the API, or am I missing something in the documentation to undo the pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a limitation of the GitLab API. It can only return a maximum of 100 requests per each call.

Comment: Thanks! Is there in turn a way to know the number of pages OR the total number of issues?

Answer (score 0):

Just to document my approach for getting the issues if anyone needs it:

```bash
issues=()                                                                            
while true; do                                                                       
    # Retrieve the current page of issues                                            
    page_issues=$(glab issue list -R $GITLAB_REPO --page $page --per-page $per_page) 
                                                                                     
    # If the page is empty, we have retrieved all issues                             
    if [ "$page_issues" == "No open issues match your search in $GITLAB_REPO" ]; then
        break                                                                        
    fi                                                                               
                                                                                     
    # Append the page issues to the array                                            
    issues+="$(echo "$page_issues" | grep -Po '#\d+\s+.*')"                          
                                                                                     
    # Increment the page number                                                      
    page=$((page + 1))                                                               
done
```